# ef context + database schema + DDD BoundedContext

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design, entity-framework-6

I understand that at least EF 6 supports multiple DbContexts. This can be used to model [BoundedContext](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html). I did some google searches but could not find a definitive answer to this question. Is it advisable to use different db schemas for different DbContexts/BoundedContext? I know that ORMs abstract away the persistence mechanisms but I personally can see parallels between shemas and ddd/ef contexts.

Comment: DbContext and Bounded Contexts are _different_ things . The bounded context has NOTHING to do with a DbContext

Comment: I know MikeSW ... but there are some similarities and IMHO it could be used as such. Any more constructive comments would be very much appreciated!

Comment: There is no similarity between them. It's like Java and Javscript, common words and they share some syntax, but different beasts. BC exist only in the Domain, DbContext is an EF specific construct. One doesn't know about the other and one shouldn't be influenced by the other. They serve different concerns and they are unrelated.

Comment: I think I rather trust experts like Julie Lerman on this. Who clearly shows that there are parallels: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx

Comment: Yeah, trust the person working for EF... You can ask Eric Evans about this, you can find him on twitter.

Comment: And btw, DDD ignores anything persistence. You don't start with the database in DDD, you start with the Domain, identifying the BC. I get it that you want to use EF, but if you want to do DDD, forget about the db

Comment: i understand all this. not sure where this is going and what your point is - it was not a pure ddd question. i can still see advantages in reflecting the bounded contexts in the persistence medium whether it is nosql/ef/nh or whatever full stop.

Comment: You've said you want to model BC starting from DbContext, I've said BC has nothing to do with DbContext or any ORM. Personally, I wouldn't care about anything DDD when doing persistence stuff. You have a repository interface that's all you need. BC and DDD are out of scope.

Comment: Ok after doing some more research (esp. in the light of cqrs) I think I am getting your point. I admit defeat (-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a possibility. As with most architectural questions, the answer is: it depends.

In this case, it depends on how your overall architecture is and how your bounded contexts are structured. If they have similar aggregates that are persisted to the same tables (that is, they're different because of the context), it might be a good idea to have different DbContexts because then you can evolve them separately.

Note though that you may be introducing hidden constraints and dependencies between your bounded contexts.

If your bounded contexts have very different aggregates, then there's no need to use different DbContexts and you can just share the same one.

Another option you might consider, is using a different DbContext for reading and writing. It also allows you to evolve your model separately. (that's more of a CQRS approach though)

Comment: Thanks. I am actually looking at CQRS at the moment. Are you aware of any implementations/source code that use CQRS in conjunction with EF.

Comment: No samples that come to mind, but a google search should yield some results. The concept is quite straightforward though, load aggregate with EF, apply the command, save aggregate with EF.